# How to put a Number in to a plist with bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, plist

I'm trying to update my com.apple.background.plist. It works but the "ChangeTime" needs to be a Number/Integer in order to work. I tried to place a -int into the code but it gives an error.

> `defaults write com.apple.desktop.plist Background '{default = {Change = TimeInterval; ChangePath = "/Users/Username/Pictures/Wallpapers"; ChangeTime =  60; ImageFileAlias = <data>; ImageFilePath = "/Users/Username/Pictures/Wallpapers/05.jpg"; LastName = "Mandy Moore011.jpg"; NewChangePath = "~/Pictures/Wallpapers"; ; Random = YES; Placement =Crop;};}'`>

Is there a other way or does somebody know how to insert a Number/integer?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few errors I found when trying to run your snippet:

- There is an extra semi colon after `NewChangePath = "~/Pictures/Wallpapers"; ;`
- I'm not sure if `ImageFileAlias = <data>;` is abbreviated, but that caused the script to choke as well.
- There is a `>` at the end of your command without a location to redirect the output of the command.